# What's the meaning to pass args to Class.new

Tags: ruby, class, instance

I came across a usage such as:

```
InvalidRequest = Class.new(StandardError)
```

I am confused that:

- what's the meaning to pass an argument to `Class.new`?
- What is the relationship between InvalidRequest, StandError and Class now?

Comment: Just out of curiosity: what exactly is it that you found lacking in the documentation of [`Class::new`](http://Ruby-Doc.Org/core-1.9.3/Class.html#method-c-new)? And, now that you know the answer to your question, do you have any suggestions on how to improve the documentation so that others like you can find the answer there?

Comment: In fact I am confused by the `Class#new` and `Class.new`, as I never stumbled upon the usage of `Class.new(AnotherClass)` before. After reading the Public Class Methods, the explaination is quite clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sets up a class with the argument as the super class.

> what's the meaning to pass an argument to Class.new?

The argument is used as the superclass for a new anonymous class, which is returned.

> What is the relationship between InvalidRequest, StandError and Class now?

`InvalidRequest` *is* a `Class` which *inherits from* `StandardError`.

---

It's functionally equivalent to:

```
class InvalidRequest < StandardError
end
```

Just in a more functional programming style.